# nodejs form data being overwritten

Tags: html, node.js

I am trying to have each html form submission create it's own timestamped file but when the form is submitted a second time it is overwritten with the new timestamp. Should I put this in a loop?

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Thank you for your inquiry, someone will contact you shorty.');
  fs.writeFile(timeEntry+'submission.txt', req.body.businessname, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('Wrote data to file.txt');
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  });
  fs.appendFile(timeEntry+'submission.txt', req.body.contactname, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('Wrote data to file.txt');
    } else {
  throw err;
    }
  });`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you have `timeEntry` defined but, you'll want to move its declaration into the `app.post()` block so its recalculated at request time (otherwise, its value will be the same for every request)

The following should work:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Thank you for your inquiry, someone will contact you shorty.');

  var timeEntry = Date.now();
  fs.writeFile(timeEntry +'submission.txt', req.body.businessname, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('Wrote data to file.txt');
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  });
});
```